# Laravel within a wordpress application

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, url-rewriting

*Context:*
I have a customer who wishes to have two small web applications built within his current WordPress application. Since I always work with a combination of Laravel / VueJS, I decided to integrate this application into WordPress. The size of the application is so small, that it would be a waste of time for me to dive into an other framework or using bare php.

*Problem:*
The web applications have to reside in the public_html folder, see below. Laravel sets the public path, which in this case is not correct. Packages/plugins also rely on this, as does Laravel mix. Because WordPress also resides in the public_html folder, this folder already contains an index.php, and some other php files. While I can place the Laravel folder structure outside public_html (security measures), I need to find a place for Laravel's index file, which also needs the adjustments so everything that needs to be accessible, is accessible.

Just to be clear. The applications will have 2 URL's which will reroute to Laravel.
xxx.com/declaraties/yyy
xxx.com/rapportages/yyy

*Folder structure:*

```
/root folder (welcome to shared hosting....)
  /app
  /bootstrap
  /config
  /database
  /node_modules
  /public_html
    /wordpress folders
    /declaraties (web app 1)
      favicon
      assets etc
    /rapportages (web app 2)
      favicon
      assets etc
  /resources
  /routes
  /storage
  /vendor
  laravel related files (env, artisan, server.php, etc)
```

Any help towards a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a try with [Laraish](https://github.com/laraish/laraish), a WordPress theme that uses Laravel.

Comment: I don't think this would be efficient at all, since you would have to rebuild the WordPress website, to work within Laraish. e.g. declaring all the routes, views, etc... What I was trying to achieve was to have a wordpress website function WITHIN laravel. Which should only be a question of htaccess and base route adjustment. Never figured it out tho...